# How to make user redirect only if you type in correct word <input>

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am making a website that has 3 inputs. Each input, i want a user to be redirected ONLY if they type in the correct word for all 3 inputs. If the user submits with none correct, do nothing. This is a similar post to my last one, but it only had 1 input which was very easy.  I am not a master at this so any feedback or solutions would be great.

```js
var slim = document.getElementById("slim");
var shady = document.getElementById("shady");
var standup = document.getElementById("standup");

function tree1() {
    slim.value === "slim";
}
function tree2() {
    shady.value === "shady";
}
function tree3() {
    standup.value === "stand up";
}
if (tree1() + tree2() + tree3() === true) {
    window.location = "https://example.com";
}
```

```html
<form action="/eyerepeat" method="get">
    <label for="fname">First name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="slim" /><br /><br />
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="shady" /><br /><br />
    <label for="action">Action:</label>
    <input type="text" id="standup" /><br /><br />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to attach [event listener on form submit button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event), inside the event callback check for the values directly without using functions (its not needed in your context), **note** that using `+` sign is wrong inside the [if statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) you just use logical operator [`&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description):

```js
document.getElementById('redirect_form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var slim = document.getElementById("slim");
  var shady = document.getElementById("shady");
  var standup = document.getElementById("standup");

  if ( standup.value === "stand up" &&
       shady.value === "shady" &&
       slim.value === "slim"
  ) {
    console.log('All equal');
  }
  else {
    console.log('Not All equal');
  }
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.location = "https://example.com";
  }, 1000)

})
```

```html
<form id="redirect_form" action="/eyerepeat" method="get">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="slim" /><br /><br />
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="shady" /><br /><br />
  <label for="action">Action:</label>
  <input type="text" id="standup" /><br /><br />
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. how would you make it so if it doesnt equal, it submits to form?

Comment: you mean to submit the form even if its not equal?

Comment: you can just remove this line `e.preventDefault();` and it will submit.

Comment: usually in validation we use `e.preventDefault();` to stop the submission of the form to make sure that we don't run in an unexpected behavior.

Comment: Glad to help, please consider [accepting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find it useful :)

Comment: when i remove the line. it does work, but when you type in the correct answer, it doesnt redirect to example.com?

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer, I removed the the redirect from the if statement, and add `console.log()` to show if its `TURE`  for all or not, after that it will redirect. check it now.

Comment: hmmm, maybe my answer isn't the right answer, check the other ones and if they works for you, accepts their answer, let me know if need help again! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your functions need to `return` a value:

```
function tree1() {
  return slim.value === "slim";
}
function tree2() {
  return shady.value === "shady";
}
function tree3() {
  return standup.value === "stand up";
}
```

To determine whether all three are `true`, use `&&`, not `+`:

```
if (tree1() && tree2() && tree3() ) {
  window.location = "https://example.com";
}
```